# Flow-based vs. Reactive programming paradigms

Tags: programming-paradigms

I am reading [Concepts, Techniques, and Models of Computer Programming](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/concepts-techniques-and-models-computer-programming) and came across **Flow-based (FBP)** and **Reactive programming** paradigms. Now I have found [the following article](http://ersaconf.org/ersa-adn/papers/adn003.pdf) from *J. Paul Morrison*, the person who invented FBP. I am also some what familiar with Reactive programming. But I am having hard time to differentiate this two paradigms. Both belong to Declarative and also under Dataflow paradigm. But **what** really sets them apart? I would like a concise answer with greatest distinction between these two approaches outlined.

Comment: The idea that there are "programming paradigms" is not necessarily well-founded. It is probably more acurate to talk about *styles* of programming. The choice of resources a language provides to programmers, and the way they are put together, is more a matter of design than a technical decision.

Comment: I don't believe this sort of questions has a single answer. The way in which terminology is used varies too much between authors. For instance, judging by Wikipedia's articles on dataflow programming, reactive programming, and flow-based programming, there are clearly far more parameters by which these sorts of programming can differ than these three terms can cover, and I'm not convinced at all that different authors consistently identify these terms with the same parameter values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best distinction I've found (which also makes sense) is in this quote from @chipsy from HN (brackets and emphasis mine):

> FRP **[Functional Reactive Programming]** is very similar in nature to FBP **[Flow-Based Programming]**. (even the acronyms are similar)
> The main difference is in **packaging**.
>
> The original FBP systems were still 70s-style near-metal code within
> the component design, but the architecture described a protocol just
> sufficient for statically and asynchronously connecting the components
> together, and a runtime method that is amenable to the simplistic
> approach of having each component run round-robin until all return a
> "finished" signal. It's very much an "industrial engineering"
> perspective.
>
> FRP, on the other hand, comes from the traditions of functional
> programming, and so the evaluation order computation is given a more
> academic treatment, and the languages are given more explicit syntax,
> where FBP doesn't aim to describe itself much more deeply than the
> flowcharts. **Both FRP and FBP have purity and immutability as core
> concepts.**
>
> So as I see it: **different starting point, different packaging, same conclusions.**

Source: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6267892

"Functional reactive programming (**FRP**) is a programming paradigm for **[reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)** (asynchronous dataflow programming) using the building blocks of functional programming (e.g. map, reduce, filter)." [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming)

Also, for reference, the definitions:

- "**FBP** is a particular form of dataflow programming based on [bounded buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), information packets with defined lifetimes, named ports, and separate definition of connections." [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming#Actor_model)
- "In computing, **reactive programming** is a declarative programming paradigm concerned with data streams and the propagation of change." [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)

My current understanding:

**Flow-Based Programming** approaches seems more concerned with architecting an application based on **data processing pipelines**, especially oriented towards processing **large data sets** (think distributed [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Dataflow)):

> [NoFlo](https://noflojs.org/) is a JavaScript implementation of Flow-Based Programming (FBP). Separating the control flow of software from the actual software logic. Helping you organize large applications easier than traditional OOP paradigms, especially when importing and modifying large data sets.

> With NoFlo, your application consists of **independent components** that are connected together in a **graph**. This makes it possible to split your problem in logical areas that make sense, and to see how they connect with each other.

> The MIT-licensed NoFlo library can either be used to run full **flow-based applications** or as a library for making complex workflows or asynchronous processes more manageable. It **can also be used as an Extract, Transform, Load (ETL) tool** in business applications.

Source: https://noflojs.org/

> **FBP** is a special case of dataflow programming characterized by asynchronous, concurrent processes "under the covers", Information Packets with defined lifetimes, named ports, "bounded buffer" connections, and definition of connections external to the components ...

Source: https://jpaulm.github.io/fbp/index.html

Useful references used here, and for further reading:

- FBP: https://wiki.c2.com/?FlowBasedProgramming
- FRP: https://wiki.c2.com/?FunctionalReactiveProgramming
- https://groups.google.com/g/flow-based-programming/c/ptzWzfvo6W4
- RxJS (FRP) vs NoFlo.js (FBP): https://github.com/noflo/noflo/issues/205#issuecomment-186619306
- FBP vs. FBP-inspired Systems: http://www.jpaulmorrison.com/fbp/noflo.html
- FBP: https://jpaulm.github.io/fbp/index.html